# How can i find where roll back invoked?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

Now, I use Amazon RDS, lambda, python and sqlalchemy. when I checked amazon rds performance insights, I find some rollback invoked. rollback is invoked so far.
But when i excute other query in insights, there are not error.
How can i find where is rollback invoked? or why is rollback invoked?

1. I doubt wrong query. so, I tried to send same query that i found query in performance insights. but there are no rollback.
2. I doubt traffic issue. So, I tried to send many same query about (1000000) using 'for' and 5 terminal at the same time. After I check show processlist. but there are no rollback.
3. I heard sqlalchemy.create_engine use connection pool and when connection close, sqlalchemy invoked rollback. but I don't know, How can i check this issue and this issue is solution of this problem.

this is a my rds performance insights[image]

Comment: Have you checked RDS logs?

Answer (score 2):

Rollbacks can originate from either rolling back a transaction to unwind queries, or upon returning a connection to the pool.

One way that you could get a feel for what your app is doing would be to hook into those rollback actions through the event system to enable some tracking.

There are two events that you'd need to look at:

1. [`ConnectionEvents.rollback`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.ConnectionEvents.rollback):

> Intercept rollback() events, as initiated by a Transaction.

2. [`PoolEvents.reset`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.PoolEvents.reset):

> Called before the “reset” action occurs for a pooled connection.

You could set listeners on these events that increment some counters, or perform some logging that is specific to counting the number of rollbacks. Then you'd be able to get a feel for the relative weight of transaction rollbacks vs pool rollbacks.

E.g. using some crude global counters but you can add whatever logic that you need:

```py
import logging
from sqlalchemy import event

POOL_ROLLBACKS = 0
TXN_ROLLBACKS = 0

@event.listens_for(YourEngine, 'reset')
def receive_reset(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    POOL_ROLLBACKS += 1
    logging.debug(f"Pool rollback count: {POOL_ROLLBACKS}")

@event.listens_for(YourEngine, 'rollback')
def receive_rollback(conn):
    # track a transaction based rollback
    TXN_ROLLBACKS += 1
    logging.debug(f'Transaction rollback count {TXN_ROLLBACKS}')
```

Comment: Your help make me can check increase pool_rollbacks count. Now , i find how can i controll poll_rollback. Thank you!!!